# Django Debug Toolbar Target?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-debug-toolbar

I've got a web page loading pretty slowly, so I installed the Django Debug Toolbar. I'm pretty new at this, so I'm trying to figure out what I can do with it.

I can see the database did 264 queries in 205 ms. Looks kind of high. I'm pretty sure I can cut down on that by adding some indexes and just writing better queries. But my question is: What is a "good" number that should be trying to hit here? What is generally accepted as "fast enough" and further optimization isn't really worth it. 50ms? 20ms?

Also on this same page it's showing 2500ms in user CPU. That sounds terrible to me, and I'm surprised it's so much higher than the database, which I assumed was the bottleneck. Is this maybe an indication that I am trying to do too much in python code instead of at the database layer? Would reducing the number of SQL queries help with CPU? (Waiting between queries?). Again is there some well known target response time I should be aiming for.

I'm looking for a snappy response from my clients. Right now when I click around I can feel a "pregnant pause" before the pages load.

Comment: I'm not sure the dev server is the best place to put a lot of faith in speed.  The sql queries may guide you to creating better queries though.  Set up another server (nginx/gunicorn) and see if timing isn't improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default accessing related model fields results in one extra query per model per row. Look into [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), this usually cuts down number of queries and speeds things up by a lot. I think debug toolbar shows you the actual queries, if not, need to enable sql logs before doing any query optimizations. Once you cut down number of queries to a minimum (no extra queries per pow), look for the slowest query and use EXPLAIN sql syntax to see if indexes are being used, this is another area where it can get slow especially on big data.

Usually database is the bottleneck, unless you are doing some major looping in your code. If you believe python code is slow, then need to profile it, otherwise it's just guessing.